# How can I open new mail in outlook with different user?

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, windows-authentication

I have user myuser that logged in in windows and I open the program with otheruser.

[image]

I need that then I open new mail in outlook it will open it with myuser. The code that I'm using is:

```
Outlook.Application App = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook._MailItem MailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)App.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        MailItem.To = BossName.Text;
        MailItem.CC = ClientName.Text;
        MailItem.Display(true);
```

Comment: Are you able to do so manually?

Comment: Yes. Everyone can do it by pressing shift+rightmouseclick and choosing different user for any program.

Comment: Wow... Could you please publish a screen shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your application in the context of the desired user, or

1. **you may use Impersonation:**

[WindowsIdentity.Impersonate Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w070t6ka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Be sure that outlook doesn't run in your session already. Outlook can only run once in a session - so it's not possible to logon with different Outlook-MAPI-Sessions in one Windows-Session at the same time. You Always have to reopen outlook.

2. **Multible Outlook-Profiles**

Another way is to configure multible Outlook profiles and start outlook via .net and pass the Profilename. But this can be a little bit tricky, because you always have to check if outlook isnt already running in a different profilecontext - because the Profile-Parameter will be ignored if outlook has already been opened.

```
class Sample
{
    Outlook.Application GetApplicationObject()
    {

        Outlook.Application application = null;

        // Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
        {

            // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object. Or close Outlook to open a new instance with a desired profile
            application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
            //!! Check if the application is using the right profile - close & reopen if necessary
        }
        else
        {

            // If not, create a new instance of Outlook and log on to the default profile.;
            application = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            nameSpace.Logon("profilename", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            nameSpace = null;
        }

        // Return the Outlook Application object.
        return application;
    }

}
```

3. **If possible use EWS**

Another approach would be to use EWS-API (Exchange WebServices-API) but this presupposes to have an Exchange or Office365 account. And is only usefull if you want to deal with outlook-items in the background (.Display() is not possible)
If you are using an Exchange-Account (Office365) i would prefer to do it that way... 
[Get started with EWS Managed API client applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn567668%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)